# Video stream encoding for UDP transfer

Tags: stream, udp

Im using UDP video stream broadcasting, but the output is so bad. I understand that UDP is not a reliable transfer (VCL, no option to use TCP transfer), so the answer would be in the encoding. What codec do you prefer to maintain the pixel errors at the minimum level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not the answer you want, but then I don't think that this question is easily answered. There is much ongoing research in this area and there is not *one* solution.

It also largely depends on your specific scenario:

What codec are you currently using? What resolution and framerate, how much money can you spend on infrastructure? What is the purpose of the streaming i.e. conversational, video on demand, video surveillance, etc? What types of network i.e. LAN, WAN, wireless, etc. All these factors influence the type of solution. Some options involve source rate adaptation based on RTCP receiver report information, retransmission of lost packets, forward error correction, using scalable video codecs such as H.264 SVC and I'm sure many other methods.

Regarding the choice of codec: I guess the more efficient the better, but it doesn't only depend on that but also on the configuration of the codec e.g. the i-frame interval, the network type, and so forth. You might also need to consider things like license costs, etc.